# Create class object with a tuple having tensorflow objects

Tags: python-3.x, oop, tensorflow, low-level-api

I have a parametersTheta class which creates neural network as follows:

```
class parametersTheta:
    def __init__(self, weight1, weight2,....):
        self.weightName1 = weight1
        self.weightName2 = weight2
        ...
        self.sess = tf.Session()
    def makeWorkerTheta(self, param):
        return parametersTheta(self.sess.run(functionCalculatingTensorWeights, feed_dict={...}))
```

self.sess.run creates a tuple of all the weight tensors. However, error pops up saying you need to input weight2 and onwards, i.e. the tuple goes into weight1

How can I solve this? Basically, how can I create an instance of class parametersTheta with a tuple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can instantiate class with tuple expanded to arguments like this.

```
parametersTheta(*(weight1, weight2, ...))
```

An asterisk before a tuple expand it to a corresponding arguments list.